# VB .net and C# .net working together

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have to create a new module for an existing project which was made in VB.net

It has to be made with .net but vb is not mandatory, so it is possible to create this new funcionalities in C# and integrate them?

If so, how can I do it? advantages and disadvantages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of note: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a2c7tshk.aspx

Answer (score 6):

VB.Net and C# can co-exist in the same application (Visual Studio solution), but not in the same assembly (Visual Studio project).

Answer (score 1):

Create another assembly. The new assembly can use C# and reference the VB assembly if needed in order to extend the functionality

You can also make the new assembly share the same namespace as the VB assembly and when both dlls are referenced in another projects the namespaces will merge (adding functionality to the namespaces without necessarily extending the original dll)

You can't have VB/C# in the same assembly as far as I know